# How to find Lebesgue measure of a set?

Tags: real-analysis

How to find $\lambda_3(A)$, where

$$A = \{ (x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 | z^2 < \frac{x^2}{4} + \frac{y^2}{9} < 2z \}$$

I know that measure of set A is given by $\int_A 1 d\lambda_3$.

I suppose that here I should use  Fubini Theorem, however I can't figure out how to get the limits of integration.

When we integrate sum of intervals can we write it out as a sum of integrals of intervals?

What I mean is when we have $$\int_A 1 d\lambda_3$$ I want to rewrite it as
$$\int_{0}^{2} \int_a^b \int_c^d 1 dxdydz$$
where $c,d$ depend on $y$ and $z$ while $a,b$ depend on $z$.

However since in the definition of set $A$ there are squares, set of possible values of $x$ is not an interval, but a sum of few intervals, since we can write $\frac{36z^2 - 4y^2}{9} < x^2 < \frac{72z - 4y^2}{9}$.

So my question is is it true that in such situation we can write:
$$\int_{0}^{2} \int_{a_1}^{b_1} \int_{c_1}^{d_1} 1 dxdydz + ... + \int_{0}^{2} \int_{a_k}^{b_k} \int_{c_k}^{d_k} 1 dxdydz$$

where $a_i, b_i, c_i, d_i$ would be boundary points of intervals of possible value of variable.

Comment: You do *not* "integrate sum of intervals".

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Looks like multivariate calc fun. Note that $\frac{x^2}{4} +\frac{y^2}{9}$ is part of an ellipse, so spherical or cylindrical coordinates might help

Comment: I think what you mean is: do we have $\int_A{\bf 1}d\lambda_3=\int_B{\bf 1}d\lambda_3+\int_C{\bf 1}d\lambda_3,$ where $B=\{ (x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3\mid z^2 < \frac{x^2}4+\frac{y^2}9\}$ and $C=\{ (x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3\mid\frac{x^2}{4} + \frac{y^2}{9} < 2z \}.$ This is obviously false.

Comment: I would start by noting $z^2 < 2z \iff 0 <z < 2$

Comment: Please Janik, do not just ask. Work a little before and present your attempts. https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask The rule on this site is to close without hints every "no effort question".

Comment: @Stasiek Janik note my edit pls

Answer (score 4):

Go to these eliptic cylindrical coordinates: $F:(0, \infty) \times (0, 2\pi) \times \mathbb{R}$,
$$
F(r, \theta, u) := (2r\cos(\theta), 3r\sin(\theta), u)^\top.
$$
which have volume element
$$
\mathrm{det}DF(r, \theta, u) = \mathrm{det}
\begin{pmatrix}
2\cos(\theta) & -2r\sin(\theta) & 0 \\
3\sin(\theta) & 3r\cos(\theta) & 0 \\
0 & 0& 1
\end{pmatrix} = 6r.
$$
Further note that $z^2 < 2z$ for all $(x, y, z) \in A$ which is equivalent to $z \in (0, 2)$. So in our new coordinates, $A$ becomes
$$
A = \lbrace (r, \theta, u) \in (0, \infty) \times (0, 2\pi) \times (0, 2): u^2 < r^2 < 2u \rbrace
$$
which means that the integral transforms to
$$
\int_A~\mathrm{d}\lambda_3 = \int_0^{2\pi} \int^2_0  \int^{\sqrt{2u}}_{u} 6r~\mathrm{d}r  ~\mathrm{d}u ~\mathrm{d}\theta = \int^{2\pi}_0 \int^2_0 -3\left(u-2\right)u~\mathrm{d}u = \int^{2\pi}_0 4~\mathrm{d}\theta = 8\pi.
$$
Correct me if I made a computational error.

Answer (score 1):

The area of the ellipsis $\displaystyle\frac{x^2}{4}+\frac{y^2}{9}\le r^2$ is $6\pi r^2$, hence the integral has value
\begin{equation}
I = 6\pi \int_0^2 (2 z - z^2) d z = 6\pi\left(4-\frac{8}{3}\right)=8\pi
\end{equation}